# Extending django-cms toolbar login

Tags: django, django-cms, django-authentication

I am developing a website with django/django-cms and would like to extend the toolbar login with some other custom validation (LDAP). The issue is I'm not quite sure how to extend the validation of this form. I have found within the django-cms package, the file `toolbar.py`

```
class CMSToolbarLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['prefix'] = kwargs.get('prefix', 'cms')
        super(CMSToolbarLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

From what I understand, this form extends the AuthenticationForm from django and adds its own custom username field. Is that correct?

Also how would I get this form to redirect to another view on failure? Like if the user is in db and user/pass match then login, but if user is not in db redirect to another view so I could retrieve the user from my ldap directory?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to enable custom login backend that will to the job of authenticatiion. There is no need of overwriting any form.

You can use `django-auth-ldap` and add in your settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

You can see more at: https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/install.html